# Simplest way to exchange messages between two *nix machines

Tags: network-programming

What is the *simplest* way to exchange messages between two *nix machines connected with an ethernet cable? I'm looking for a way to write a really low-level program (maybe in C/C++) to send simple messages from one machine to the other, without error checking and without using any socket library.

I know that, in UNIX, "everything is about files", but google searches about files and networking didn't lead me to the information I hoped to find.

Thank you.

Comment: You could easily write a socket program to send message in C/C++/Java/Any langauge.

Comment: Do you mean writing my own socket library? Ok but I don't know how, that's the point. I'm open to suggestions if there are come tutorials or books about it.

Comment: No, you already have socket libraries available in all major programming languages like C, Java, Python,etc. You should just make a program to send message from one system to other system using LAN connection. **If you don't want to use pre-defined libraries, you could custom make one based on the previously available ones**.

Comment: Well yes, using an available library would be good as well. Do you know where I could download the source code of one of these libraries? That would be really helpful. I tried searching the web but only reached websites where I could download the _pre-compiled_ library (where you can only see the header files but not the implementation itself)

Comment: Actually, I am also unable to find that on the web. Actually, nobody cares about those nowadays. BTW, just like Arduino, you could send bytes(data) to other IP address. I don't know how to go further deep. Maybe, the implementation is based on assembly, OR another low-level code. I am not sure, SORRY for I couldn't help further. **AND, if you get that, please let me know too.**

Comment: I found an open source library [here](http://apr.apache.org). I'll be glad to let you know if there's something else interesting. Thanks anyway.